# How to achieve CheckBox related operations inside a GridView in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm working on a conf room booking app. So, I'd like to have Checkboxes in all the working timings. I mean Working Hours as columns and Checkboxes as rows. The following operations are to be performed for which I require guidance:

For the selected date, rows should, by default, populate the record based on the booking status. Checkboxes should be disabled for the booked and enabled to allow the booking. The catch is, for the future dates, say nobody has started booking, and hence, by default, all the checkboxes should be loaded and enabled in a row for booking. Pls guide me on how to start. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your GridView should have a column with a CheckBox to which you are going to bind if it is booked or not:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Booked" SortExpression="booked">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="checkBoxBooked" Checked='<%# Eval("booked").ToString()=="1" ? false : Eval("booked").ToString()=="0" ? true : true %>' runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

As you can see, "booked" would be 1 or 0 depending on whether it has been booked or not. That value is coming from the GridView data source by creating an appropriate query.

Hope this helps!